# i am getting issue while running my new project with ng serve command in angular 6,here am attaching my issue

Tags: angular6

E:\ngexample>ng serve
The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.

pls help me to solve this problem

Comment: I guess your project folder is some folder inside `E:\ngexample`. Suppose your project folder name is `project` then try `cd project` hit enter. Then use `ng serve` command

Comment: yahh ! now i tried by changing folder name,now it's working.thanks for your help.